# to_json :include on active record requires database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to produce a json string with one level of associations:

```
@lines = Line.joins(:mems)\
             .where("     lines.document_id = ?
                      AND lines.text <> 'root'
                      AND mems.review_after < ?", params[:id], Time.now())\
             .to_json :include => :mems
```

My development log is as follows:

```
  Line Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `lines`.* FROM `lines` INNER JOIN `mems` ON `mems`.`line_id` = `lines`.`id` WHERE ( lines.document_id = '30'
 AND lines.text <> 'root'
 AND mems.review_after < '2011-01-10 04:14:59')
  Mem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `mems`.* FROM `mems` WHERE (`mems`.line_id = 49)
  Mem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `mems`.* FROM `mems` WHERE (`mems`.line_id = 50)
  Mem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `mems`.* FROM `mems` WHERE (`mems`.line_id = 51)
  Mem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `mems`.* FROM `mems` WHERE (`mems`.line_id = 52)
  Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE (`tags`.`id` = 8) LIMIT 1
Rendered documents/review.erb within layouts/application (11.3ms)
```

As you can see, the ActiveRecord object produces a single query with an inner join. However, the to_json method queries the associated model individually for each Line record.

Is there a way to avoid these duplicate queries without writing a custom serialization method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `:include` *eager loads* related objects from the database, you'll need to use it on your *original* query.

The solution is simple: just use `includes`:

```
@lines = Line.includes(:mems)\
         .where("lines.document_id = ?
                 AND lines.text <> 'root'
                 AND mems.review_after < ?", params[:id], Time.now())\
         .to_json :include => :mems
```

Comment: how do i use to_json on my original query?

Comment: heh sorry - the to_json method also still takes the original arg: :include => :mems

Comment: full line, which produces no duplicate queries -- 85% faster! check out the very end: Line.includes(:mems).where("lines.document_id = ? AND lines.text <> 'root' AND mems.review_after < ?", params[:id], Time.now()).to_json :include => :mems

Comment: @joshs That's 85% faster than without the `:include`  on `to_json`?`

Comment: It is 85% faster when using Line.includes instead of Line.joins. Regardless of whether you use Line.includes or Line.joins, to_json requires the argument :include => :mems for mems to be part of the json string.

Comment: @joshs Hmm, interesting. I'll revise my answer to reflect that. Thanks